# Setting up environment variable in ant script

Tags: java, ant

I am using ant for building my projects, This project needs more memory then default JVM size, So I have added following line of code in the `build.xml` file.

```
<!-- setting up this value as project need this much memory to compile.-->
<property environment="env" />
<property name="env.ANT_OPTS" value="-Xms1024m -Xmx204888m"  />
```

But above line of code does not seems to have any effect as I am still getting the heap size problem. So I have decided to use a `batch` script for launching the build. The line of code in the given batch file is below

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx778m
ant -f agora-build.xml
```

This batch script successfully launch and executes the ant script. But this is not what I am looking for. Is there a way exists, so that I can setup this argument in the ant script itself?

What should i do?

Thanks,
VSD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running the Ant script in Eclipse

Right Click -> Run As -> External Tools Configuration

(Add the build if it isn't there already)

Go to the JRE tab and add the Xms and Xmx arguments to the VM arguments section.

*edit: "-Xmx204888m" I hope 2 of those 8's are typo's

Comment: No sir, I am running it form command prompt. This script supposed to be running in the command line only. Thanks

Comment: Your script above does look right. Did you try setting the variable (ANT_OPTS) in the Environment Variables in windows? Should work the same as you typed it above in the script, but worth the shot.

Comment: What about using the "Running Ant via Java" option
http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava

Comment: As i have written above, It works in a `batch` script. It must be some thing missing from my side.

Comment: Yes this link seems to be answer for my query.

Comment: Hey Vijay, can you put the solution so that other users can learn from the approach.

Answer (score 8):

If you set the option in the build script, the JVM is already up and configured; the only way to set JVM-level options from within a build file is to have Ant spawn another JVM (using the [`java` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava) as a launcher, or the [`ant` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html)).

You can also set `ANT_OPTS` as an environment variable; that will affect all Ant builds you run and pass the provided options to the JVM that Ant runs in.